# How to make post call to c# pagemodel class

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-ajax, jquery-ajax

I've a c# class like below sample code

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
public JArray Transactions { get; set; }

 public IActionResult OnPostTranJarray(int transaction_number, string cardholder)
    {
    
    dynamic Trans = GetTransactions(transaction_number,cardholder);
    
    return Trans;
   }

}
```

i just wanted to Make a post call  inside the IndexModel Class.
I've use these below code in jquery

```
 $.post("https://localhost:7197/Transactions?handler=TranJarray?transaction_number="+transactionNumb+"&cardholder="+cardHolderName, response => { 
      alert("response",response);
    });

    
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://localhost:7197/Transactions?handler=TranJarray?transaction_number="+transactionNumb+"&cardholder="+cardHolderName,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",    
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data)
    {  
        alert("success");
        fnLoadTbl();
      
    }
    });
```

But it's not hitting to the method.. but if i make GET Request to some other method in that class it's working. so let me know if you have any idea. Thanks..

Comment: You already asked this question and got an answer which will work. If that solution is not working for you, I'd strongly suggest you respond to the user who asked for details.

Comment: No actually it has some difference .. and here I've more clear content it's about onpost method and ajax so totally different question

Comment: Check for errors, sometimes you need to pass the anti forgery token as part of the request on a post.  Its a bit of gotcha.

Comment: console error showing  - "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data` parameter. 
Try this:

```
var yourUrl= "https://localhost:7197/Transactions"; //pure action
var feed = {
  transaction_number: yourNumber,
  cardHolderName: yourString
};
        
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: yourUrl,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json", 
  data: feed,
  async: true,
  cache: false,
  success: function (data) {  
    alert("success");
    fnLoadTbl();
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.